# EMV transaction log result is not expected

Tags: java, android, payment-processing, emv

I read **transaction log** to calculate **floor limits** in **terminal risk management**. I successfully read **transaction log** of **EMV card** with length is 10 lines, but why the **EMV-tags** of that result is not recognized when parsed it with **TLV Parser**?

EMV-tags: 4092 is not recognized by TLV Parser?

1.Log Format

```
REQ LOG_FORMAT: 80CA9F4F00

RES LOG_FORMAT: 9F4F289F27019F26088A029F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F370482029F36029F10209F6B30 9000

LogFormat is success
```

2.Log Entry

```
After select AID, I get log entry as follows 0B 0A
```

3.Transaction Log

```
REQ TRANS_LOG: 00B2015C00

RES TRANS_LOG: 4092AFED093EB371AC3030000030000000000000000000036080800480000360190519017B3B91CF7400000D01016100000000516D54FA000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9000

//More transaction log in here

Transaction Log is success
```

Transaction Log code:

```
private List<IApdu.IApduResp> readTransactionLog(byte[] logEntry) {
    try {
        if (logEntry.length != 2) {
            return null;
        }
        List<IApdu.IApduResp> apduRespList = new ArrayList<>();
        int sfi = logEntry[0] & 0xFF;  // 11
        int rows = logEntry[1] & 0xFF; // 10 rows
        int successCount = 0;
        for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
            IApdu.IApduReq req = APDU.createReq((byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xB2, (byte) row, (byte) ((sfi << 3) | 0x04));
            if (req == null) {
                break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "REQ TRANS_LOG: " + row + " " + sfi + " : " + bcdToStr(req.pack()));
            byte[] cmd = isoCommand(req.pack());
            if (cmd == null) {
                return null;
            }
            IApdu.IApduResp unpack = APDU.unpack(cmd);
            if (unpack == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "RES TRANS_LOG: " + bcdToStr(unpack.getData()) + " " + unpack.getStatusString());
            if (unpack.getStatusString().equals("9000")) {
                ++successCount;
                apduRespList.add(unpack);
            } else if (unpack.getStatusString().equals("6A83")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (successCount > 0) {
            transLogResponse.setApduResponse(apduRespList);
            return apduRespList;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag `0x9F4F` *Log Format* define sequence of Tag + Length pairs. In other words the Value of Tag `0x9F4F` contains **TLs** - the sequence of TL(1) + TL(2) + TL(3) + ... + TL(n).

*Transaction Log* contain the sequence of Values for the correspondent Tags with mentioned lengths, i.e. **Vs** - the sequence of V(1) + V(2) + V(3) + ... + V(n).

**Log Format parsing**

```
TLV:#"9F4F289F27019F26088A029F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F..6B30" # EMV, Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x9F4F:#"9F4F289F27019F26088A029F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F..6B30" # EMV, Log Format
  - tag: "9F4F"
  - len: "28" #  // 40
  - val:#"9F27019F26088A029F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F370482..6B30" # Log Format.
    - x9F27:#"9F2701" # EMV, Cryptogram Information Data (CID)
      - tag: "9F27"
      - len: "01" #  // 1
    - x9F26:#"9F2608" # EMV, Cryptogram, Application
      - tag: "9F26"
      - len: "08" #  // 8
    - x8A:#"8A02" # EMV, Authorization Response Code (ARC)
      - tag: "8A"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
    - x9F02:#"9F0206" # EMV, Authorised Amount (Numeric)
      - tag: "9F02"
      - len: "06" #  // 6
    - x9F03:#"9F0306" # EMV, Amount, Other (Numeric)
      - tag: "9F03"
      - len: "06" #  // 6
    - x9F1A:#"9F1A02" # EMV, Country Code, Terminal
      - tag: "9F1A"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
    - x95:#"9505" # EMV, Terminal Verification Results (TVR)
      - tag: "95"
      - len: "05" #  // 5
    - x5F2A:#"5F2A02" # ISO 7816, Currency Code, Transaction
      - tag: "5F2A"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
    - x9A:#"9A03" # EMV, Date, Transaction
      - tag: "9A"
      - len: "03" #  // 3
    - x9C:#"9C01" # EMV, Transaction Type
      - tag: "9C"
      - len: "01" #  // 1
    - x9F37:#"9F3704" # EMV, Unpredictable Number
      - tag: "9F37"
      - len: "04" #  // 4
    - x82:#"8202" # EMV, Application Interchange Profile (AIP)
      - tag: "82"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
    - x9F36:#"9F3602" # EMV, Application Transaction Counter (ATC)
      - tag: "9F36"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
    - x9F10:#"9F1020" # EMV, Issuer Application Data (IAD)
      - tag: "9F10"
      - len: "20" #  // 32
    - x9F6B:#"9F6B30"
      - tag: "9F6B"
      - len: "30" #  // 48
```

**Transaction Log data parsing**

```
data:#"4092AFED093EB371AC3030000030000...0000"
- x9F27:
  - val: "40" # Cryptogram Information Data (CID).
    # 01______ - bits 8-7, TC
    # _____000 - bits 3-1, (Reason/Advice/Referral Code), No information given
- x9F26:
  - val: "92AFED093EB371AC" # Cryptogram, Application.
- x8A:
  - val: "3030" # Authorization Response Code (ARC). // 00 - Approved
- x9F02:
  - val: "000030000000" # Amount, Authorised (Numeric). // 30000000
- x9F03:
  - val: "000000000000" # Amount, Other (Numeric).
- x9F1A:
  - val: "0360" # Country Code, Terminal. // 360 - Indonesia
- x95:
  - val:#"8080048000" # Terminal Verification Results (TVR).
    - B01: "80"
      # 1_______ - bit 8, Offline data authentication was not performed
    - B02: "80"
      # 1_______ - bit 8, ICC and terminal have different application versions
    - B03: "04"
      # _____1__ - bit 3, Online PIN entered
    - B04: "80"
      # 1_______ - bit 8, Transaction exceeds floor limit
    - B05: "00"
- x5F2A:
  - val: "0360" # Currency Code, Transaction. // 360 - Rupiah
- x9A:
  - val: "190519" # Date, Transaction. // 2019.05.19
- x9C:
  - val: "01" # Transaction Type. // cash
- x9F37:
  - val: "7B3B91CF" # Unpredictable Number (UN), Terminal.
- x82:
  - val:#"7400" # Application Interchange Profile (AIP).
    - B01: "74"
      # _1______ - bit 7, SDA supported
      # __1_____ - bit 6, DDA supported
      # ___1____ - bit 5, Cardholder verification is supported
      # _____1__ - bit 3, Issuer Authentication is supported
    - B02: "00" # RFU
- x9F36:
  - val: "000D" # Application Transaction Counter (ATC). // 13
- x9F10:
  - val: "01016100000000516D54FA000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" # Issuer Application Data (IAD).
- x9F6B:
  - val: "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: I'm confused about the floor limit. If sum of amount >= Terminal Floor Limit, set the 'Transaction exceeds floor limit' bit in TVR to 1. Is sum of amount came from transaction today only (one day), or all transactions without time limit? Thanks

Comment: Terminal application or EMV kernel compare Terminal Floor Limit with each Transaction Amount and set TVR Byte 4 bit 8 accordingly. The summary calculation of amounts for the periods (Day, month, total, etc) at the side of Card application, if it is applicable. And these cumulative total amounts may trigger card decision to go online.

Comment: Transaction Log as a Security Protection Against Split Sales. That means the sum added is the result of today's transaction and compared to the floor limit. Is it really like that?

Answer (score 1):

RES TRANS_LOG is not TLV encoded. It contains only value fields. You have to parse according to log format you have received in earlier response of log format which has TAG and length and according to this format log data will be parsed.
After parsing it will be as follows:

> 9F27 01 40
>   9F26 08 92AFED093EB371AC
>   8A   02 3030 
>   9F02 06 000030000000
>   9F03 06 000000000000
>   9F1A 02 0360
>   95   05 8080048000
>   5F2A 02 0360
>   9A   03 190519
>   9C   01 01
>   9F37 04 7B3B91CF
>   82   02 7400
>   9F36 02 000D
>   9F10 20 01016100000000516D54FA000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   9F6B 30 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000